# how to convert blob url to base64 in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I use `image_picker: ^0.8.5+3` for upload image in web flutter.

```
  Future _imgFromGallery() async {
    final image = await picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 800);
    }
```

But when I print `image.path` the uploaded photo, it shows me this  address with 'blob' `blob 'http://localhost:22808/8108f482-37c1-4b7f-9e9c-9e65d1810f5a'`
I want to convert image to `base64` and  for this I use the following code. But this conversion is not done correctly and completely.Can you help me in this matter?

```
 final bytes = html.File(image.path.codeUnits, image.path);
 Uint8List b = Uint8List(bytes.toString().length);
 String img64 = Base64Encoder().convert(b);
```

‍‍‍

Comment: Please share the exact printout from your print()! And what exactly is it that you want an answer to? I didn't quite get it...

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work because you're trying to decode a `Uint8List` that has no data in it.  You have a URL; can you not just use `package:http` to visit the URL and get the byte data from the HTTP response?

Comment: I finally want to convert the uploaded photo  to base64. But in the web, url of the uploaded photo, it has a blob. Therefore, according to the search I made, before converting to base64, I converted it to `Unit8List` and then to base64, but this conversion was not done correctly.

Comment: are u able to pick image using html.File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I had to add the ‍‍`image_picker_for_web: ^2.1.8`  and convert the photo to `Base64` with the code below:

```
 var image = await picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 800);
 var imageForWeb = await image.readAsBytes();
  String base64Image = base64Encode(imageForWeb);
```